# Vaadin Upload File Path from Testing using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, gwt, upload, vaadin

Any reason why this wont set the file path for the Vaadin Upload Component in selenium.

The file path remains unset and when the click happens it trys to upload null. The file does exist in my local directory.

```
$(UploadElement.class).first().findElement(By.className("gwt-FileUpload")).sendKeys("/tmp/test.xlsx");
$(UploadElement.class).first().findElement(By.className("v-button")).click();
```

Comment: notes to mention: Using vaadin 7 here and the latest version of TestBench 4

Comment: Out of curiosity, what driver are you using? Just tested with Vaadin 7.6.3, TestBench 4.0.1.aplha1 & PhantomJS 2.1.1 and everything works as expected.

Comment: @Morfic Using Vaadin 7.6.3 and TestBench 4.0.3 I struggled with the safari driver to get anything to read into the gwt-FileUpload. Firefox and Chrome at least noticed something was selected. And the new line of code below seemed to actually allow it to upload on click. Tbh, im finding TestBench (Selenium without a recorder) very pernickety and time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got it working

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("/tmp/test.xlsx"); 
$(UploadElement.class).first().findElement(By.className("v-button")).click();
```